# PostgreSQL, add row to table when a row is created in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger function, to create a new row, in a table, when a value is modified or created in another table. But the problem is that I need to insert in the other table, the primary key that provoked the trigger function.
Is there a way to do it?

Basically, when an insert or update will be done in table 1, I want to see in table 2 a new row, with one field filed with the value of the primary key of the row in table1 that provoked the trigger.

```
begin
    INSERT INTO resultados_infocorp(id_user, Procesado)
    VALUES (<PRIMARY_KEY>,false)
    RETURN NEW;
End;
```

This is because if Procesado is false, thank to the id_user I will make some validations, but the ID of the user is necesary and I cant do it from the backend of my project, because I have many db inputs.

[image]

PD: The primary key of the new table is a sequence, this is the reason why I am not passing this arg.

```
CREATE TRIGGER resultados_infocorp_actualizar
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF id_user, fb_id, numdocumento, numtelefono, tipolicencia, trabajoaplicativo
    ON public.usuarios
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.update_solicitudes_infocorp();
```

Comment: Please show the trigger definition also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not shown the trigger definition. Still if you want the PK value then something like:

```
INSERT INTO resultados_infocorp(id_user, Procesado)
    VALUES (NEW.pk_fld,false)
```

Where pk_fld is the name of your PK field. Take a look here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

for what is available to a trigger function. For the purpose of this question the important part is:

NEW

Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers. This variable is null in statement-level triggers and for DELETE operations.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Klaver , I don' t need the PK of the new row, but of the row that provoked the trigger.

Comment: Again the trigger definition would be nice.  Still I'm pretty sure that either NEW.pk_fld or OLD.pk_fld are what you want as they represent the row that fired the trigger.

Comment: I am not sure why the difinition would be useful but here is the entire code: ```CREATE FUNCTION public.add_solicitudes_infocorp()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
     NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$begin
 INSERT INTO resultados_infocorp(id_user, Procesado)
 VALUES (TG_TABLE_NAME ,false)
 RETURN NEW;
End;$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.add_solicitudes_infocorp()
    OWNER TO doadmin;``` I know that old and new are useful when the trigger change someting in the sametable, but in my case, one table provoke an insert in another table.

Comment: No, I'm looking for the ```CREATE TRIGGER``` definition. Please add that to your original question as it will be easier to read there.

Comment: I added what you asked me.

Comment: No that is part of the the function definition. In psql do \d on the table and it will show you the triggers on the table.

Comment: But you cant do the trigger in the table if you don't have a function definition. That is why I am doing that first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217421/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-jonathan-prieto).

Comment: I think that now I added what you were looking for.

Comment: The final code is: ```begin
    INSERT INTO resultados_infocorp(id_user)
    VALUES (NEW.id_user);
    RETURN NEW;
End;```

Comment: No, that will not work. You cannot RETURN NEW in an AFTER trigger. If you will not read the doc link I sent or my comments, then there is really no point in carrying on this conversation